# Generating an Array printing at Random

Tags: java, arrays, random, character

Working on a question that asks to create an array of 100 characters ("`*`" in this case) that are generated at random. The total of the characters must be a 100 and they must be printed on 10 rows where each row prints a random amount of "`*`" but the total amount of characters ("`*`") at the end must be 100.
Very unfamiliar with Java as I just started. I have got the following so far and need assistance.

Below is a sample output and the code I have so far :

## Output:

```
0 |*******
1 |*********
2 |***************
3 |*******
4 |******************
5 |*******
6 |****************
7 |*****
8 |****
9 |************
```

## Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random; 

public class ArrayTest{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    
    
    // The for loop to ensure there is a total of 10 rows 
    
      for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
      Random bytes = new Random();
    
   // Printing the  '*' at random
      int number = bytes.nextInt(10);
      for(int b=0; b<number; b++){
        for(int c=0; c<number; c++){
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }            
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean generated at random? What is random here? Number of `*`s or random characters?

Comment: Where is your array? Also, never instantiate a `Random` **in** a loop. The first `9` rows can be random. The last one is dictated by the preceding nine (if the total is to be 100).

Comment: The number of "*" has to be a total of 100. What has to be random is the amount per row that are printed. for instance row 1 can have 8 row 2: 7, row 3: 1 but the total after of the * has to total 100
I have been trying with you tube on how to do this unsuccessfully and was just told about this platform

Comment: So what happens after 10 rows? What if the total number of `*` is not 100 after 10 rows?

Comment: If choosing the number of `*`s in a row at random, then how do you assure that after 10 rows, you will have 100 `*`s?

Comment: can there be rows without any `*`?

Comment: @Maddy yes there can be

Answer (score 0):

If empty lines are permitted you can do something like following. You can introduce a `count` to be the total number of '*'s and let the generated random number to be the number of stars for a row. After printing each row, get the remainder of the count and pass it into the random generator. Check the code below:

```
class ArrayTest{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Random bytes = new Random(); //take this out of the loops as mentioned in the comments
        int count = 100; //keep track of 100 '*'s

        for(int a=0; a < 10; a++){ //limit to random 10 rows
            if (count > 0) { //if count reaches 0, don't print anything
                int rand = bytes.nextInt(count + 1);
                for(int b=0; b < rand; b++){ //print random amount of '*'s
                    System.out.print("*");
                    --count; //decrement count for each '*' print
                }
            }
            System.out.println(); //note the next line print is outside the inner for loop
        }
    }
}
```

Issue with this approach is if the random number is close to 100, in the first few iterations, last few rows would be empty.

to print at least 1 '*':

```
Random bytes = new Random(); //take this out of the loops as mentioned in the comments
    int count = 90; //keep track of 100 '*'s, since we anyway print 10 '*'s, keep the count to 90, 
    for(int a=0; a < 10; a++){ //limit to random 10 rows
        System.out.print("*"); //print 1 anyway
        if (count > 0) { //if count reaches 0, don't print anything
            int rand = bytes.nextInt(count + 1);
            for(int b=0; b < rand; b++){ //print random amount of '*'s
                System.out.print("*");
                --count; //decrement count for each '*' print
            }
        }
        System.out.println(); //note the next line print is outside the inner for loop
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Maddy 
Unfortunately its kinda printing all over the place over and over all the while leaving blanks... Appreciate the attempt. If I wanted to restrict it so that each row atleast has an element what should I add to the code ? 
Thanks once again!

Comment: Added the change. check now. If you want it to be fully randomized, you have to expect the scenarios like all '*' being printed in a single row.